# In Android, how to read the current button background image?

Tags: android, image, button, background

I am trying to find a way to read a button’s background image name (I have three different possible images for each button in the button state xml file) so that every time a user click on the button I can put that image name value in if statement to see if I need to change the button image to the next image or not (of the 3 images)

I tried this

button1.getBackground()

Then I used the toast to show the valie of that using this:

Toast.makeText(TreActivity.this, String.valueOf(button1.getBackground()) , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

I was thinking it will give me one of my 3 button state images but instead it gave me this: 
android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable@44f01d58

So how can I get the current background drawable image currently assigned to the button?

Thanks in advance for everyone's help!

Comment: Cast it to a `BitmapDrawable` and call [getBitmap()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#getBitmap%28%29). You'll get the actual image bitmap...

Comment: I am researching how to do your idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will working for u 
my my app i used this getting image from image view.

```
img_View11.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {            
    public void onClick(View v)  {           
        ImageView iv = (ImageView)v;                 
        Drawable d = iv.getDrawable();                                   
        }                
       }
    });
```

Comment: Does it return the id of the image view background? I need the id because I want to pass it to another activity.

Comment: you can't get id of the imageview, you will get Image only. btw you can pass image from one activity to another..